# Are there any issues if buying a Samsung Galaxy S3 without memory?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, external-sd

If I buy a phone without memory or minimal memory, can I change to a memory card that I buy somewhere else? I was thinking of a class 10 32gb or 64gb.

Are there any concerns with doing it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about removable storage (microSDXC)? It's not required, and it's expandable up to 64GB.

Without removable storage, you will be using the built-in storage which can be either 16GB or 32GB.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III)

Comment: I was thinking of the internal storage then. Should I be buying a phone with a Class 10 storage and when I reach the extent of 16GB or 32Gb, then invest in an external 64Gb? I am upgrading from my $50 nokia so the leap is huge.

Comment: On this page at the bottom is some customization before buying. The memory dropdown appears to be internal memory then. http://www.techrific.com.au/product_info.php?products_id=3694

Comment: Thank you for the help. I understand things now. The selection I am talking about must be external.